# Javascript deepmerge breaks objectid

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm not new to javascript, but this is my first time using node.js.  I'm trying to create a basic query to feed to mongoose, then add conditions later.
I'm using deepmerge to merge these hashes together, but the objectid gets mangled.

Original Hash:

```
query = {
        $and: [
            {"unsubscribe.status": { "$ne": "unsubscribed" }},
            {"isDeleted.status": { "$ne": true }},
            {'advisorCommunities': { $in: communities }},
            {"memberType": 'Advisor'}
        ]
    }
```

console dir:

```
  '$and': [
    { 'unsubscribe.status': { '$ne': 'unsubscribed' } },
    { 'isDeleted.status': { '$ne': true } },
    {
      advisorCommunities: {
        '$in': [
          ObjectID {
            _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
            id: Buffer(12) [Uint8Array] [
               93,   2, 154,  46,  92,
              186,  99,   7, 226, 238,
              107, 170
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    { memberType: 'Advisor' }
  ]
}
```

Hash to merge in:

```
engageQuery = {
  '$and': [
    {
      '$or': [
        { nextEngagementDate: { '$exists': false } }
      ]
    }
}

var deepmerge = require('deepmerge');
query = deepmerge(engageQuery, query);
```

The advisorCommunities has changed:

```
{
  '$and': [
    {
      '$or': [
        { nextEngagementDate: { '$gte': 2021-06-10T15:17:54.627Z } },
        { nextEngagementDate: { '$exists': false } }
      ]
    },
    { 'unsubscribe.status': { '$ne': 'unsubscribed' } },
    { 'isDeleted.status': { '$ne': true } },
    {
      advisorCommunities: {
        '$in': [
          {
            _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
            id: {
              '0': 93,
              '1': 2,
              '2': 154,
              '3': 46,
              '4': 92,
              '5': 186,
              '6': 99,
              '7': 7,
              '8': 226,
              '9': 238,
              '10': 107,
              '11': 170
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    { memberType: 'Advisor' }
  ]
}
```

here's the error from mongoose:

```
(node:34291) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{
  _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
  id: {
    '0': 93,
    '1': 2,
    '2': 154,
    '3': 46,
    '4': 92,
    '5': 186,
    '6': 99,
    '7': 7,
    '8': 226,
    '9': 238,
    '10': 107,
    '11': 170
  }
}" at path "advisorCommunities" for model "Member"
    at model.Query.exec (/protopia/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4360:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (/protopia/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4454:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:34291) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:34291) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I spent a hour trying some weird stuff to create a custom function, etc., but failed.  Please help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question, but I'm not sure it's the right answer.

```
query = deepmerge(engageQuery, query, {clone: false});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge

Adding clone: false to the options fixed the problem.  However, according to the npm documentation that option is deprecated.  Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Comment: You don't need the $and property: By default, mongoose assumed that if there are multiple properties in an object, that they are all in an $and. Then just use the spread operator, and voilà; Should now be one object.

Answer (score 0):

use `isMergeableObject` option with `is-plain-object` module maybe better. offical example:

```
const isPlainObject = require('is-plain-object')
 
function SuperSpecial() {
    this.special = 'oh yeah man totally'
}
 
const instantiatedSpecialObject = new SuperSpecial()
 
const target = {
    someProperty: {
        cool: 'oh for sure'
    }
}
 
const source = {
    someProperty: instantiatedSpecialObject
}
 
const defaultOutput = merge(target, source)
 
defaultOutput.someProperty.cool // => 'oh for sure'
defaultOutput.someProperty.special // => 'oh yeah man totally'
defaultOutput.someProperty instanceof SuperSpecial // => false
 
const customMergeOutput = merge(target, source, {
    isMergeableObject: isPlainObject
})
```